# Loading some from config and some other from configSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have a config file with `<appSettings>` tag. I want some of them to be constant, and load some of them from another config file.

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="commonKey1" value="commonValue1" />
  <add key="commonKey2" value="commonValue2" />
  <add key="commonKey3" value="commonValue3" />
  <!-- ??? -->
</appSettings>
```

AdditionalSettings.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="AdditionalKey1" value="AdditionalValue1" />
  <add key="AdditionalKey2" value="AdditionalValue2" />
</appSettings>
```

Result: `Web.config` after compilation should behave like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="commonKey1" value="commonValue1" />
  <add key="commonKey2" value="commonValue2" />
  <add key="commonKey3" value="commonValue3" />
  <add key="AdditionalKey1" value="AdditionalValue1" />
  <add key="AdditionalKey2" value="AdditionalValue2" />
</appSettings>
```

It's quite easy if ALL values are stored in separate file :

```
<appSettings configSource="Settings.config" />
```

but I have no idea how to merge two files if some tags should be present in base file, and only additional tags should be loaded from a separate one.

I've also tried

```
<appSettings configSource="Settings.config">
  <add key="commonKey1" value="commonValue1" />
  <add key="commonKey2" value="commonValue2" />
  ... etc
```

But it won't work: `A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements.`

Of course I can't also just create two tags (one with concrete values and another with configSource), it results in:

```
There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined
```

Can anyone help? Is it even possible, or there is another approach to the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After wasting way too much time on this, I came to the soultion:

```
<appSettings configSource="Settings.config">
  <add key="commonKey1" value="commonValue1" />
  <add key="commonKey2" value="commonValue2" />
  ... etc
```

is illegal, but the:

```
<appSettings file="Settings.config">
  <add key="commonKey1" value="commonValue1" />
  <add key="commonKey2" value="commonValue2" />
  ... etc
```

is perfectly fine... So it all came down to changing `configSource` attribute to `file` attribute. Now it works fine.

Comment: Not working for me using ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1, it gives an exception when parsing the configuration file, saying that the "file" attribute is illegal.

Comment: @hardsetting The reason I was getting this error was because I copy and pasted the entire appSettings section from the web.config which included the file attribute into the included file. After removing the file attribute from the included file I no longer received the error.